# Explicit shaped array with nonconstant bounds when solving ODE with Runge-Kutta

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

```fortran
program Bernoulli_Equation
    integer N ,i,u(i+1),p(i+1),rho(i+1),u(i),p(i),rho(i),u(N), p(N), rho(N) ! Nombre d'itérations
    real t , k1,l1,m1,k2,l2,m2,k3,l3,m3,k4,l4,m4 ,dt! Variables dépendantes
    
    ! Conditions initiales
    u(1) = 0.0
    p(1) = 1.0
    rho(1) = 1.0
    N=100
    dt=0.01
    open(unit=5,file='OHRK4.txt')
    ! Boucle de calcul
    do i = 1, N-1
        t = i * dt
        
        ! Calcul des pentes
        k1 = dt * du_dt(u(i), p(i), rho(i))
        l1 = dt * dp_dt(u(i), p(i), rho(i))
        m1 = dt * drho_dt(u(i), p(i), rho(i))
        
        k2 = dt * du_dt(u(i) + 0.5*k1, p(i) + 0.5*l1, rho(i) + 0.5*m1)
        l2 = dt * dp_dt(u(i) + 0.5*k1, p(i) + 0.5*l1, rho(i) + 0.5*m1)
        m2 = dt * drho_dt(u(i) + 0.5*k1, p(i) + 0.5*l1, rho(i) + 0.5*m1)
        
        k3 = dt * du_dt(u(i) + 0.5*k2, p(i) + 0.5*l2, rho(i) + 0.5*m2)
        l3 = dt * dp_dt(u(i) + 0.5*k2, p(i) + 0.5*l2, rho(i) + 0.5*m2)
        m3 = dt * drho_dt(u(i) + 0.5*k2, p(i) + 0.5*l2, rho(i) + 0.5*m2)
        
        k4 = dt * du_dt(u(i) + k3, p(i) + l3, rho(i) + m3)
        l4 = dt * dp_dt(u(i) + k3, p(i) + l3, rho(i) + m3)
        m4 = dt * drho_dt(u(i) + k3, p(i) + l3, rho(i) + m3)
        
        ! Mise à jour des variables dépendantes
        u(i+1) = u(i) + (k1 + 2.0*k2 + 2.0*k3 + k4) / 6.0
        p(i+1) = p(i) + (l1 + 2.0*l2 + 2.0*l3 + l4) / 6.0
        rho(i+1) = rho(i) + (m1 + 2.0*m2 + 2.0*m3 + m4) / 6.0
    end do
    
    ! Affichage des résultats
    do i = 1, N
        t = i * dt
        write(*,*) t, u(i), p(i), rho(i)
    end do
    
contains
    
    ! Fonctions pour calculer les
```

this is what terminal donne to me :

```
    2 |     integer N ,i,u(i+1),p(i+1),rho(i+1),u(i),p(i),rho(i),u(N), p(N), rho(N) ! Nombre d'itérations
      |                        1
Error: Explicit shaped array with nonconstant bounds at (1)
bernouli.f90:6:4:

    6 |     u(1) = 0.0
      |    1
Error: The function result on the lhs of the assignment at (1) must have the pointer attribute.
bernouli.f90:7:4:

    7 |     p(1) = 1.0
      |    1
Error: The function result on the lhs of the assignment at (1) must have the pointer attribute.
bernouli.f90:8:4:

    8 |     rho(1) = 1.0
      |    1
Error: The function result on the lhs of the assignment at (1) must have the pointer attribute.
bernouli.f90:34:8:

   34 |         u(i+1) = u(i) + (k1 + 2.0*k2 + 2.0*k3 + k4) / 6.0
      |        1
Error: The function result on the lhs of the assignment at (1) must have the pointer attribute.
bernouli.f90:35:8:

   35 |         p(i+1) = p(i) + (l1 + 2.0*l2 + 2.0*l3 + l4) / 6.0
      |        1
Error: The function result on the lhs of the assignment at (1) must have the pointer attribute.
bernouli.f90:36:8:

   36 |         rho(i+1) = rho(i) + (m1 + 2.0*m2 + 2.0*m3 + m4) / 6.0
      |        1
Error: The function result on the lhs of the assignment at (1) must have the pointer attribute.

    end
```

I try to write Bernoulli equation in fortran using runge-kutta

Comment: The error message in the first error is quite clear, what is `u(i+1)` supposed to be or declare at that place?

Comment: I can't imagine how that is related to Bernoulli's equation, but never mind. If you use indices - e.g. u(1) or u(N) or u(i+1) - then you are implying that u is an array, and both that fact, and its size, must be declared. Actually, if you output your values of u, p and rho at the end of the timestep then none of them need to be an array in the first place.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask].  I agree with lastchance that your variables  u, p and rho do not have to bee arrays, because you are just solving an ordinary differential equation and you do not have to and often you do not want to store the values from all timesteps. You can print or save the values in every timestep.

Answer (score 0):

The error message points to this line

```
    integer N ,i,u(i+1),p(i+1),rho(i+1),u(i),p(i),rho(i),u(N), p(N), rho(N) ! Nombre d'itérations
```

The comment suggests that `N` is the number of iterations, that here means timesteps.

The variable `i` is an iteration variable and is correct to be an integer. However, given the comment specific to `N`, it should probably be moved to a separate line.

However, the rest is nonsensical. You repeat `u`, `p` and `rho` three times, each time in a different form. That is illegal. Also, they certainly should.not be `integer`.

If you want to store all `N` values of these variables in an array, you need

```
   real u(N), p(N), rho(N)
```

However, think whether you really need to store all values, it is normally not needed and it is clumsy when `N` is not known in advance. Alternatively, you may at least want to use allocatable arrays.